# Add-AzureAccount in Azure-runbook fails with: The given key was not present in the dictionary

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-automation, runbook

The two lines of code worked perfectly in one of my Azure-Powershell-Workflow runbook until recently.

```
$azureCredential = Get-AutomationPSCredential –Name "<asset-name>"
Add-AzureAccount -credential $azureCredential
```

Now it fails with the error-message `Add-AzureAccount : The given key was not present in the dictionary.` The inspection of the `$azureCredential` did not bring up anything suspicious.

**Q** What must I do to get it going again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can happen in Add-AzureAccount if the credential doesn't have access to any RDFE (Azure Service Management) subscriptions. You can follow the directions [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-automation-authenticating-to-azure-using-azure-active-directory/) to add the credential to an RDFE subscription.

Comment: How did you reassign the subscription to the user, so i can update my answer?

Comment: Sorry, my comment before was incorrect, therefore I deleted it. I removed and afterwards added the user and reassigned the co-admin role. Then it worked again.